# playonlinux is unable to find 32bits OpenGL library you might encounter problem with your games

Tags: wine, playonlinux

My hardware configuration is

Intel core2duo 2.93GHz
4GB DDR2 RAM
MSI G31 motherboard
Seagate 80GB PATA harddisk

I'm new to linux and I'm having this problem since few days, it was not there before. Can you please help?

This is my terminal screen when I try "playonlinux".

```
bishek@bishek-MS-7529:~$ playonlinux
[main] Message: PlayOnLinux (4.1.8) is starting
[clean_tmp] Message: Cleaning temp directory
[Check_OpenGL] Warning: 32bits direct rendering is not enabled
[Check_OpenGL] Message: 64bits direct rendering is enabled
[main] Message: Filesystem is compatible
[install_plugins] Message: Checking plugin: Capture...
[install_plugins] Message: Checking plugin: ScreenCap...
[install_plugins] Message: Checking plugin: PlayOnLinux Vault...
/usr/share/playonlinux/bash/startup_after_server: line 38: [: : integer expression expected
/usr/share/playonlinux/bash/startup_after_server: line 38: [: : integer expression expected
[maj_check] Message: List is up to date
playonlinux is unable to find 32bits / 64bits OpenGL library
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
~: locate libGL.so.1
/usr/lib/fglrx/libGL.so.1
/usr/lib/fglrx/libGL.so.1.2
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1.2
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1.2
/usr/lib32/fglrx/libGL.so.1
/usr/lib32/fglrx/libGL.so.1.2
~: export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa
~: playonlinux
```

Comment: Can you explain what that does and how it's a fix?

Comment: @Enkouyami: if some program can't find a lib there's a chance you can find it for her. In the above code the lib is found: `/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1`. So now we have to notify `playonlinux` about it. The `export` line does it. I'm not sure it will work.